# Is it possible to draw a line on a MatrixPlot that would reflect density of row values?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, matrix

I have a `MatrixPlot` with some data and I'd like to draw a vertical lines representing the "average" (density) of that data for each row. 
Something like this for example: 
[image: MatrixPlot with lines representing a certain value per line]

How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `Epilog`.

Comment: @march Thanks, that works great!
But now I have another problem. The matrixPlot kinda averages the data out so I am not sure which part of the data it is using for each row. Is there a way to access the data he used for a specific row?

Comment: @FrankT That is completely  different question!

Comment: Is the average made by `MatrixPlot` necessary? If not, how about using `ArrayPlot` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we understand "average" as density of colors on `MatrixPlot`:

Matrix:

```
m = {{4, 7, 2}, {3, 0, 7}, {5, 2, 9}};
```

Solution only for 3 x 3 matrix (can easily be extended to arbitrary matrix):

```
tmp = 3/2 - (#[[1]] - #[[-1]])/Total[#] & /@ m;
coord = Transpose[{
  Transpose[{tmp, Range[2, 0, -1]}],
  Transpose[{tmp, Range[3, 1, -1]}]
  }];
```

I like `Show`, so:

```
Show[
 MatrixPlot[m], 
 Graphics[{Red, Thickness[0.02], Line[coord]}]]
```

Result ("average" is some **weighted deviation from the center**):

[image]

Comment: I really liked this solution! Could you explain a bit more how you calculated the average on line 2 ` tmp = 3/2 - (#[[1]] - #[[-1]])/Total[#] & /@ m; ` ?

I don't really understand those last operators, & /@ m , thanks

Comment: @FankT, let's take an example `{3,0,7}`. We may treat it like a density. Would it be some `{3,0,3}` or `{7,0,7}` (simetric), we would get the line in the middle, that is for the 3  element of the matrix on 3/2. But we have to correct that, and that is what pure function does.

Comment: @FrankT, (pure_function_body&) /@ m is mapping of some function to the variable, witch is list, m. [Map](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) is the main function in whole Mathematica so study it carefully. It applies the function to each element on the list

Answer (score 0):

```
MatrixPlot[{{3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 7}, {9, 8, 4}},
 Epilog -> Line[{{1, 1}, {3, 3}}]]
```